# How can I display a variable in a dynamic text field?

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I have an input textfield on the screen and I have it set to the text that a user enters is saved as a variable and is later called upon o be displayed in a dynamic text box. It's kinda like a high score kind of system, but with multiple variables.

Here is the frame actions where the variables are being set (at least I think they are)

```
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var data:String = username.text + " " + date.text + " " + company.text;
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(data, username.text + " " + date.text + " " + company.text + ".txt");
}

button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_8);

function fl_ClickToGoToNextFrame_8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}

var nameperson = username.text;
var dateperson = date.text;
var companyperson = company.text;
```

And are the actions where I'm trying to display the variables in another frame:

```
var nScore:Number = 0;

for(var i:Number = 0; i < aQuestions.length; i++) 
{
     if(aUserAnswers[i].toUpperCase() == aCorrectAnswers[i].toUpperCase()) 
     {
          nScore++;
     }
     if(i == aQuestions.length - 1) 
     {
          score_txt.text = nScore.toString();
     }
}

endresult_name.text = nameperson;
endresult_date.text = dateperson;
```

Comment: Try setting an actual data-type for your variables. Example `var nameperson : String = username.text;`. Also remember variables created inside a function only work within that function (just in case you are doing anything like that and getting stuck). Your complication is likely using code on multiple frames, why can't it all be on frame1?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you set these variables straight when you get to your 1st frame (the text inputs are empty at that point). You need to set them after the user have filled them out and clicked on the button:

```
var nameperson:String;
var dateperson:String;
var companyperson:String;

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var data:String = username.text + " " + date.text + " " + company.text;
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    file.save(data, username.text + " " + date.text + " " + company.text + ".txt");

    nameperson = username.text;
    dateperson = date.text;
    companyperson = company.text;
}
```